Business Objects 4.3 dependent variables
I'm using Business Objects 4.3 to query my HR system and have 4 objects on the report from one table with multiple records.  I want the latest record and the corresponding values for each object.
Example:



Person ID
Check Date
Renewal Date
Reference Number




4566
1/1/23
31/12/23
123


4566
1/1/24
31/12/24
456



All columns currently show MULTIVALUE against the person ID (key field) as the check data is from a sub query.  I have used Max on the Check Date to get the latest entry but I don't want to put max on the other columns in case of errors in the data.  EG if I put max on both date columns I would get the bold entries instead of a renewal date of 31/12/23



Person ID
Check Date
Renewal Date
Reference Number




4566
1/1/23
31/12/24
123


4566
1/1/24
31/12/23
456



So how can I make the variable for Renewal Date or Reference Number dependent on the entry returned for Check Date, ie. return the whole corresponding record?  I tried where check date = max(check date) but it didn't like that.
Thanks
